# selenium how to set implicitly wait?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am using selenium-side-runner for automated testing, but the test site has a loading animation effect, I can not select the label for the first time, resulting in an error. I want to use an explicit wait to solve this problem.
However, I don't know how to add it to selenium-side-runner.

this is my selenium-side-runner code:

```
result = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "selenium-side-runner",
        "-w",
        "5",
        "-c",
        "goog:chromeOptions.args=[--verbose"
        ",--no-sandbox, --disable-extensions, --dns-prefetch-disable, --disable-gpu] browserName=chrome",
        "--server",
        settings.SELENIUM_ADDRESS,
        file_path,
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#:%7E:text=Implicit%20Waits,life%20of%20the%20WebDriver%20object.):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```